# Bitwise bit shifting and why this solution works

Tags: arrays, go, bit-manipulation, bit, shift

I've been doing code fights on codefights.com and I came upon this problem below.  I have figured out the problem on my own, but when i researched other peoples solutions I found one that was much shorter than mine, but I cant seem to understand why they did what they did.

The question goes:

> You are given an array of up to four non-negative integers, each less than 256.
>   Your task is to pack these integers into one number M in the following way:
>
> The first element of the array occupies the first 8 bits of M;
>   The second element occupies next 8 bits, and so on.
>   Return the obtained integer M.
>
> Note: the phrase "first bits of M" refers to the least significant bits of M - the right-most bits of an integer. For further clarification see the following example.
>
> Example
>
> For a = [24, 85, 0], the output should be
>   arrayPacking(a) = 21784.
>
> An array [24, 85, 0] looks like [00011000, 01010101, 00000000] in binary.
>   After packing these into one number we get 00000000 01010101 00011000 (spaces are placed for convenience), which equals to 21784.

Their answer was:

```
func arrayPacking(a []int) (sum int) {
    for i := range a {
        sum += a[len(a) - i - 1] << uint((len(a) - i - 1) * 8)
    }
    return
}
```

How is this code returning the right amount of shift just by using 0, 8, 16, etc. intervals?  I've been researching bitwise a lot lately, but I still can't seem to reason why this works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You shift by multiples of 8, because bytes are 8 bits. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: This seems pretty trivial despite the `len(a)-i-1` bit is a little annoying (you are calling len O(n) times! though n<=4). The bitwise shifting is exactly how you deal it on paper, move `0` 16 bits and you get the leading 8 zeroes, `85` 8 bits and get the middle `01010101`. If you haven't notice, 256 = `1<<8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write the solution in Go. We convert little-endian, base-256 digits to a base-2 (binary) number. Shifting left by 8 bits multiplies by 256.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pack(digits []int) (number int) {
    // digits are little-endian, base-256 (1 << 8 = 256)
    for i, digit := range digits {
        number += digit << uint(i*8)
    }
    return number
}

func main() {
    a := []int{24, 85, 0}
    m := pack(a)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oo_n7CiAHwG

Output:

```
21784
```

Now you should be able to figure out their ugly looking answer:

```
func arrayPacking(a []int) (sum int) {
    for i := range a {
        sum += a[len(a) - i - 1] << uint((len(a) - i - 1) * 8)
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the bitshifting by multiples of 8 is the same as muliplying by multiples of 256, e.g. `x << 0*8 == x * 256⁰`, `x << 1*8 == x * 256¹`, `x << 2*8 == x * 256²` etc., so the code can be rewritten like this, using `math.Pow`:

```
func arrayPacking(a []int) (sum int) {
  for i := range a {
    sum += a[len(a) - i - 1] * int(math.Pow(256, (len(a) - i - 1)))
  }
  return
}
```

Or is your question why this sort of packing works?

Comment: You forgot type convertion.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add it for me? I don't write Go, and forgot the details.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as a solution also.  I chose the following answer because it was broken down a bit more and written in go (which i feel can help future readers who have the same problem).  I appreciate your response.